# Submit topology to storm cluster through streamparse

Tags: jar, apache-storm, word-count, topology, streamparse

I am trying to use streamparse to develop and submit the topologies to the storm cluster.

Since streamparse has its default wordcount topology to help user test the cluster, most of the tutorials I could find online is about submitting this default wordcount example to the storm clusters.

My question is how to submit **my own** topologies? For example, I have a topology named 'mytopology'. Per streamparse's document, I tried

```
sparse submit --environment prod --name mytopology
```

and my config file is

```
{
    "serializer": "json",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "userx",
            "ssh_password": "mypasswd",
            "nimbus": "10.XXX.XX.210",
            "workers": ["10.XXX.XX.206"],
            "log": {
                "path": "/home/userx/stormapp/splog",
                "max_bytes": 1000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "virtualenv_root": "/home/userx/stormapp/venv"
        }
    }
}
```

However, the log showed that

```
JAR created: _build/wordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

was created and submitted to Nimbus.

Isn't the

```
--name mytopology
```

supposed to find the mytopology.py and build something like mytopology.jar and submit that?

Then I checked the project.clj file, the top line is

```
defproject wordcount "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Now it is confusing. Should I also configure this file? When I do

```
sparse submit --environment prod --name mytopology
```

Does it do something that is related to this file? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your have first creating your wordcount project using the following  command : `sparse quickstart wordcount`
In this case, "wordcount" will be the name of the topology that will be submitted to Storm using the `sparse run` command.
Now if you want to submit another topology, say `mytopology`, you have to create another quickstart project called `mytopology` and edit the `config.json` file to suit your technical environment. You cannot just copy and rename the "wordcount" project's folder as I guess you've done because "wordcount" appears in your `project.clj` file.